# How to merge two dataframes that have increasing number based column headings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, merge

I have two data frames at the moment that look a bit like this but a lot larger. Dataframe 1:

| Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Q5 | Q6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | e | f |

Dataframe 2:

| Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | d | f |

So,dataframe 2 is the same as dataframe 1 but it is missing Q3 and Q5 from dataframe 1. Q3 in dataframe 2 is the equivalent of Q4 in dataframe 1 and Q4 in dataframe 2 is the same as Q6 in dataframe 1. I want to merge these two tables together to look something like this:

| Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 | Q5 | Q6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| a | b | NULL | d | NULL | f |

My tables in reality are a lot larger and have a lot more columns and a couple more missing questions in the second table than shown in this example. So I was just wondering if anyone has a way of doing this so that I do not have to manually rename and fill all the columns. Thank you.

Comment: dataframe2 has q3. at any rate try : ``pd.concat([df1, df2])``. you can rename the  columns in dataframe2 before concatenating

Comment: @sammywemmy I would have to add and rename all of the columns after the missing ones in df2. I know this is one way of doing it but my actual tables go up to Q50 so renaming every column after a missing one manually would be very time-consuming.

Comment: how do you determine the equivalents? what I mean is what is the criteria for matching q4 in dataframe2 to q3 in dataframe1? maybe that might help in creating a function or some other way to automate the combination, beyond the manual renaming

Comment: @sammywemmy In the actual tables, the second row of the table is used for the question name. E.G row 1 - Q1, Q2, Q3 row 2- whats your name?, age?, location?.

Comment: @sammywemmy Even then some of the wordings for the questions differ slightly so I have manually made a list of questions that are in df1 but missing from df2.

Answer (score 1):

I think the operation you are describing is `pd.concat` as @sammywemmy said.

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Q1': ['a'], 'Q2': ['b'], 'Q3': ['c'], 'Q4': ['d'], 'Q5': ['e'], 'Q6': ['f']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Q1': ['a'], 'Q2': ['b'], 'Q3': ['d'], 'Q4': ['f']})

print(pd.concat([df1, df2]))
```

Output:

```
  Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4   Q5   Q6
0  a  b  c  d    e    f
0  a  b  d  f  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Please refer to the comments on the original post for information why this wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a helper function to renaming the second dataframe automatically. All you need to know is the list of missing questions. I used here `df1` as a source of names but you could also use a generator of successive 'Q1', 'Q2'... 'Qn'.

```
def rename(df, skip=[], ref=df1):
    skip = set(skip)
    cols = (c for c in ref.columns if c not in skip)
    return df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, cols)))

pd.concat([df1, rename(df2, skip=['Q3', 'Q5'])], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  Q1 Q2   Q3 Q4   Q5 Q6
0  a  b    c  d    e  f
1  a  b  NaN  d  NaN  f
```

###### helper function with Qx generator

This one relies purely on position, so you can use it if the names are imperfect even in df1

```
def rename(df, skip=[]):
    skip = set(skip)
    cols = (f'Q{i}' for i in range(1, len(df.columns)+len(skip)+1)
            if i not in skip)
    return df.set_axis(cols, axis=1)

pd.concat([rename(df1), rename(df2, skip=[3,5])], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: maybe None for `skip` instead of list as an argument in the function definition?

Comment: This is a great idea. I am a bit confused what skip [] is meant to be though

Comment: This is the default if no missing. Try the second code. As @sammywemmy hinted, a clean library would probably use `None` as default and handle this case with an if/else. NB. I fixed a typo.

Comment: @mozway in my implementation I am have made it so that my columns are named e.g. Q1-what is your name?. Would this still work with the Qx generator

Comment: It should work with the second, try it. If you have issues provide a sample of your real headers

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
nind1 = df2.columns.values.copy()
nind2 = np.unique(np.append(nind1, qindf1notdf2))
deff = len(nind2)-len(nind1)
for i, x in enumerate(nind2):
    if x in qindf1notdf2:
        nind2[nind2>=x] = [re.sub('\d', lambda s: str(int(s.group(0)) + 1), y) for y in nind2[nind2>=x]]

ncols = nind2[:-deff]
df2.columns = ncols
pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Output:

[image]